# Navigation bar doesn't display inline with header text

Tags: html, css

## What I want to do

I would like to display the navigation bar inline with the header for the site I am creating.

## HTML and CSS

```css
header {
     max-width: 1000px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 10px;
     background: blue;
    }
    
    #logo, nav {
     float: left;
    }
    
    #logo {
     width: 40%;
     background: red;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     height: 100px;
     line-height: 100px;
     font-size: 24px;
    }
    
    nav {
     width: 60%;
     background: #333;
     height: 100px;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    #top-nav {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
    }
    
    #top-nav li {
     float: left;
     background: #333;
    }
    
    #top-nav li a {
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 14px 16px;
    }
    
    #top-nav li:hover > a {
     background: #111;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
     position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     min-width: 160px;
     z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content li {
     float: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title></title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <div id="logo">
            <span>My Site</span>
         </div>
         <div style="clear:both;"></div>
         <nav>
            <ul id="top-nav">
               <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#">Item</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-content">
                     <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Item</a>
               <li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
         <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      </header>
   </body>
</html>
```

## What broke the code

Adding `padding: 10px;` to `header` seems to have broken the code, as it was working fine previously, as in the nav bar was displaying properly inline with the header. I cannot seem to get my head around the issue, I really do not see what causes it.

Also, I understand that this is not Code Review, but any remarks as to what can be improved upon/formatted differently in the code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `10px` of `padding` to your `header` makes it wider than `1000px`, it will be `1020px` wide. To prevent this, you should use `box-sizing: border-box`.

More information: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

**EDIT**:

That's not the problem here, I misread your question. The `div's` were not inline, because of the `div` with inline styling `clear: both`, since it clears the floating within the parent div.

If you remove it, the `#logo` and `nav` will be floating next to each other:

```css
header {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: blue;
}

#logo, nav {
    float: left;
}

#logo {
    width: 40%;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 24px;
}

nav {
    width: 60%;
    background: #333;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

#top-nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

#top-nav li {
    float: left;
    background: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div id="logo">
        <span>My Site</span>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul id="top-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Item</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Item</a><li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This greatly helped for the padding exceeding the max width. Along with the answers about removing the first `<div style="clear:both"></div>`, my problem is now solved.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` div to display the nav bar inline with the logo.

Also add this to your css to eliminate list styling:

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unwanted `<div style="clear:both"></div>` the one under logo immediately, remove it and your issue will be fixed, check the snippet below:

```css
header {
     max-width: 1000px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 10px;
     background: blue;
    }
    
    #logo, nav {
     float: left;
    }
    
    #logo {
     width: 40%;
     background: red;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     height: 100px;
     line-height: 100px;
     font-size: 24px;
    }
    
    nav {
     width: 60%;
     background: #333;
     height: 100px;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    #top-nav {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
    }
    
    #top-nav li {
     float: left;
     background: #333;
    }
    
    #top-nav li a {
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 14px 16px;
    }
    
    #top-nav li:hover > a {
     background: #111;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
     position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     min-width: 160px;
     z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content li {
     float: none;
    }
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title></title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <div id="logo">
            <span>My Site</span>
         </div>
         <!-- This clear div is making your nav below the logo-->
         <!--<div style="clear:both;"></div>-->
         <nav>
            <ul id="top-nav">
               <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#">Item</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-content">
                     <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Item</a>
               <li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
         <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      </header>
   </body>
</html>
```

## Update

As @A. Ahmed mentioned, you could also insert this rule:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

To beautify the design.